# value for a detected object using python

Tags: python, opencv

how can i give value for a detected object 
for example give it a name(object a ,object b)
i'm using Opencv and python
here is a code for a detection of blue object:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(cap.isOpened()):
#cpature frame by frame
ret,frame=cap.read()
if(ret):        #if cam read is successful

    #ops here:
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #bleu color
    lower = np.array([110, 50, 50], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array([130,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower,upper)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask = mask)

    #disp the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: check your indentation

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use mapping which allows you to map one datatype into another. It is something like this `{ object_1:"name_1",  object_2:"name_2".....so on}`. So, now you would be able to get your `object_1` back by just calling its name which is `name_1`. I am not so familiar with python but i think this is called **`Dictionary`** in python. I have used similar thing in C++.